# mysql_connect(): Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was just wondering if it was possible for certain databases to block SQL accesses through `mysql_connect`. I recently downloaded XAmpp and created a SQL database using my own computer as a local host and wrote a PHP file that accessed that database.

However, when I tried to change the username and host settings so that Xampp would run the PHP files that would then connect to the external SQL database of a free hosting site that I'm trying to use (biz.co.nf), I got the following error message:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection refused in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/...

Right now I'm thinking either:

1. My login credentials to that database are incorrect, or
2. Somehow the host blocks SQL accesses from external users, but if I were to load my php code into the server using FileZilla, it should work okay?

Please let me know if this is the case.

I'm also fairly certain I have the right login credentials.

Here's what I have:

```
$host = "fdb13.biz.nf";
$username = "1764941_login";
$password = ________;
$db_name = "1764941_Login";!
$tbl_name = "Members";

//Connect to server
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("Cannot Connect!");
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("Cannot select Database");
```

with my server settings according to my website...
[image: Settings]

Of course, I omitted my password.

Comment: Can you paste your MySQL connection code?

Comment: All access has to be granted. In the granting process a host has to be identified. A host can be a wild card (advised against), or a specific host name/ip address. So yes, if nobody granted you access, then you can not connect to the database.

Comment: Added my code and a picture if it helps, sorry it wasn't done earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Connections are refused from remote locations to MySQL for security reasons. You can add your IP Address to enable MySQL to listen from your database by following the instructions in this link - [Cyberciti biz tips on enabling remote access to mysql database server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) In your case, add the IP address of the location where your PHP script.
I would also say that

```
mysql_connect
```

is deprecated in PHP. Use mysqli instead. Check the comments in the link - [PHP original MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)

Comment: So it works on Xampp locally because it's not blocked from a remote location? Do you think that if I were to load the same PHP file onto the server using FileZilla, it would then work?

Comment: Yes, It works in Xampp because you are in local. If you want to load the PHP file to the remote server, you also need to make sure it supports PHP. If it does, then Yes